# multiprocessing : farming out python functions to a cluster

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cluster-computing

I am wondering if I can execute/run python functions through multiprocessing package on a grid/cluster rather than on the same local machine. It will help me create 100's of jobs on which same function has to be used and farm them out to our local cluster through DRMAA. I am not sure if this is possible or makes sense to do with child processes/forks.

Any example or advice would be helpful.

PS: cross posted on python-list

Thanks!
-Abhi

Comment: When I was attempting to do something of this nature, I ended up using SubProcess and ssh.  Not a great solution, but forking to a remote machine doesn't exactly make sense.

Comment: what about this page: http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing

Comment: @RickyA : good link. Since there are lot of packages there it would be nice to hear some used cases that have worked for people. -Abhi

Comment: How about using celery? http://celeryproject.org/

Comment: Sorry. I have no working knowledge with any of them. Did hear of celery though...

Comment: @Arifwn : not heard about celery until but sounds interesting...one thing that I am not sure is, can celery interact with the local cluster for farming out jobs through SGE/UGE like flavors of scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Typically for this we use something like MPI.

Have an arbiter who's sole job is to assign tasks to nodes and check the liveness of nodes.(Pool) every script should be identical and contain all the code you need and distributed to all the nodes.

Once that has been set up maintain a queue of tasks and parameters (method name + arguments) for each node to accomplish and queue the result back into the arbiter.

Naive example:

```
def do_something(arg1, arg2):
  return arg1 + arg2

def get_next_task():
  task, args = server.retrieve_task()
  result = task(args)
  server.queue_result(result, node_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  if sys.argv[1] == '-a': # arbiter
    arbiter()
  if sys.argv[1] == '-n': # node
    run_node()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `multiprocessing` module *mostly* works on the local machine. The exception being [remote managers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#using-a-remote-manager).

The advantage of using a remote manager is that you don't need anything extra beyond a standard python install. But you'd have to deal with issues like distributing your client code to all machines et cetera. And of course all machines need to have python installed.

There are a host of different options for running on clusters and the like. See the [parallel processing](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) page on the Python wiki.

Comment: I don't think this is *strictly* true: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#using-a-remote-manager
-But it's not really what ``multiprocessing`` is about.

Answer (score 0):

[Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/) may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One other possible option is [iPython](http://ipython.org/).  They have a nice parallel processing tutorial.